# Taxonomy of viruses

Tags: virology, taxonomy

There is a distinction drawn in the [ICTV code](https://ictv.global/about/code) between  "valid names" and "accepted names".

Valid names are those that are published and comply with the rules outlined in the code, while accepted names are those valid names that have been added to the [Index](https://ictv.global/taxonomy).

My question is what is the correct way of introducing new names in a publication for them to be considered valid. Should they be introduced e.g. as simply `new genus` *`Xxxxxvirus`* or should they be supplied with an explicit "tax.nov.": *`Xxxxxvirus`* `gen. nov.`. Are quotation marks needed around names indicating that they are not yet accepted? Should there be any other indication that they are not yet accepted?